# Could the Kinect SDK be used to count the number of humans entering or leaving a room?

Tags: kinect

- My  first goal would be to detect a single individual entering/leaving a room.
- Then a few individuals entering/leaving a room at the same time.
- Finally, if it's possible, detect people on wheel chairs.

Is this feasible with the Kinect SDK?

Comment: For a nice Kinect People Counter OpenSource Project take a look at http://johan.cc/2011/09/02/rf11-kinect-tracking/

Answer (score 4):

The Kinect SDK delivers a skeleton array. You can count the players in that array.
Besides that there is a SkeletonFrameReady Event that occurs if a skeleton is detected and something changed.

So you can detect people. 
You can detect multiple people, but I believe a maximun count of 4 at one time.
I don't know about the wheel chair. I guess it is possible.

Comment: Currently its 2 players with full body and 4 more that just map 1 point per player

Answer (score 2):

As juergen d said, it's absolutely possible to detect people entering / leaving the Kinect Sensor's field of view as long as it's not more than four at the same time. Also, the sensor definitely recognizes people sitting in a wheelchair, although their skeleton data might be useless apart from the upper half of their body (leg joint data will be messed up for the sensor) - but since you only need to see if there's anybody in the room, you should be fine.

Edit: From the 1.5 version on (released in May 2012), the Kinect SDK explicitly supports seated application scenarios by offering a "seated" mode (from [Kinect Blog: What's new in 1.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/new.aspx)):

> Provides the ability to track users’ upper body (10-joint) and overlook the lower body if not visible or relevant to application. In addition, enables the identification of user when sitting on a chair, couch or other inanimate object.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you had multiple Kinects hooked up to your computer. As far I know each Kinect can only detect 6 people, and track 2 at a time. And since my Kinect can detect me crawling on the floor, I would think it would be able to detect a person in a wheel chair. Now the new version has a [`SkeletonTrackingMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.skeletontrackingmode.aspx) which has a `Seated` member.